# Significance of Atmakaraka and Bhrigu Bindu in astrology?

Tags: astrology

What is the importance and significance of atmakaraka and bhrigu bindu in one's horoscope and in general?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Definition of atmakaraka]
[image: importance]

https://kupdf.net/queue/133113539-brihat-parashara-hora-shastra-vol-1-en-gi-isht-rans-i-a-tion-c-ommenlary-annotation-and-editing-by-r-santhanam-pdf_59f615b9e2b6f57565027663_pdf?queue_id=-1&x=1631706058&z=MTAzLjI3LjguMTA0 (wait for 10 seconds )

Here Chapter 32 (starting from page 316, type page 316 in the column when directed to home page) is fully on atmakaraka . And 9-12 shloka tells importance of atmakaraka.

Comment: Blogs are not a valid source. Please add verses from astrological classics (eg. Brihat Parasara Hora Shastra etc.).

Comment: I couldn't find Bhrigu Bindu , but only atmakaraka , so I edited my answer

Comment: now is it fine ?

Comment: If you could extract the quoted piece and also explain it a bit, that'd be helpful

Comment: @sbharti I already have attached screen shot of relevant text. I can't explain sorry , I have no knowledge about this , I can just provide scriptural basis :-(